# Inserting new line when joining files in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have two text files that I want to combine ..I am using the below code to do that ..the issue is at the start of the second file this code is inserting some weird characters like spaces..Is there a way to insert a new line instead of using writeline.

```
  Set txsOutput = FSO.CreateTextFile(strOutputPath)
    Set txsInput = FSO.OpenTextFile(strInputPath,1)         
         txsOutput.Writeline txsInput.ReadAll
```

Thanks

Comment: This may help about inserting blank lines: `txsOutput.WriteBlankLines n` where n is a number of blank lines you want to insert. Also try `txsOutput.Writeline Trim(txsInput.ReadAll)`, this removes spaces from beginning and end of the input.

Answer (score 0):

.ReadAll() reads the trailing EOL(s) of the file. .Writeline will add a further EOL. Use .Write instead to get an exact copy of the first input file as the head of the output file.

If the "weird characters like spaces" are - unwanted - parts of the first file, you'll have to use string ops (Instr, Left, Replace, ...) or a RegExp to clean the data.

If they come from the second file (assuming you used .ReadAll for that too), you should check the encoding of that file and/or clean the data using the methods above.